# Vertical navigation with content sliding out using jQuery and background image change

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create something that works like [this](http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/38395.html) but doesn't have any submenus. When I click on a navigation item the background image changes and the content slides out like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5291718/1.jpg) (this is what the test site is suppose to look like) with all manner of content inside the box.

I'm very beginner when it comes to jQuery and would like some help on where to start. I've looked for tutorials everywhere but nothing this specific. If anyone could point me in the right direction, or a template I can learn from that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the jquery animate function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonID').click(function() {
        $('#divToSlide').animate({width: 'toggle'});
    });
});
```

You can find more info here:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

As for the changing background, you can use jquery to set the css background property when clicked

```
var $backgroundURL = www.imageURL.com/image.jpg;
$('#divToChange').css({'background-image':'url("'+$backgroundURL'")'});
```

The complete code will look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonID').click(function() {
        $('#divToSlide').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        var $backgroundURL = www.imageURL.com/image.jpg;
        $('#divToChange').css({'background-image':'url("'+$backgroundURL'")'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Great! You've sent my on my way, I had a follow up question but figured it out myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/fade.html

a good place to start with. Disable all options with options : http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#options_docs

Place youe menus above superized, and on click fade to the corresonding image using API call: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#api_docs

Now place your menu above this using css positiong and z-index

add click events to your menu items,

When clicking on a menu item do the following:

```
goto corresponding slide image
show corresponding content
```

Start by just showing/hiding corresponding content, then use animate function to animate width or animte position.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out and answering. This seems like a viable option but CoreyRS got me one first. :)